# Correct use of & in java

Tags: java

```
if ( 25 <= si & < 30 )
```

isn't working and I can't find a way to google information on the proper use of &.

The error message that comes up says it expects > to be where & is.

Answer (score 8):

The correct syntax would be

```
if ( 25 <= si & si < 30 )
```

Note that **this is *NOT* using the bitwise `&` operation!!**

In this context, the LHS and RHS of the `&` operator are boolean, so Java will use the non-short-circuiting logical AND operation.

You could also write this as:

```
if ( 25 <= si && si < 30 )
```

... i.e. using the short-circuiting logical AND operator.

Which form should you use?

- From a semantic perspective, the `&` and `&&` will both give the right answer because the LH and RH subexpressions are side-effect free.
- From a performance perspective, I would expect the two versions to be optimized by the JIT compiler to the same (or equivalently performing) native code.  But if the optimizers don't do that, the difference in performance between the two versions is most likely negligible when considered in the context of the complete application.
- From a readability perspective, the `&&` form is probably better ... but only because lots of Java programmers will misread the `&` form because they don't understand that `&` **in Java** is not necessarily bitwise!

Comment: Your last point is correct, just look at all the other answers that incorrectly state that `&` is not a logical and.

Comment: My answer is fixed. I'd appreciate an undo on the down vote. (If it was yours, that is.)

Comment: @Code-Guru - it wasn't.  Besides, I don't see how your comment relates to >>my<< Answer ...

Comment: I was just trying to get your attention. I guess I could have just posted my comment on my answer with an @ tag instead \*shrugs\* My bad.

Comment: IMO this is the most thorough answer. Thanks for taking the time to provide all this detail!

Answer (score 0):

Note that `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` are binary operators which require a integer value on both sides. The compiler is complaining because you don't have anything between the `&` and the `<` in your if condition.

Also, you should learn the difference between the `&` and `&&` operators. (I have been corrected about what I thought the difference was. See [15.22.2. Boolean Logical Operators &, ^, and |](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2) and [15.23. Conditional-And Operator &&](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) in the Java specification for details.)

With all that put together, the correct code is

```
if (25 <= si && si < 30)
```

Finally, for future questions it will be very helpful for us to answer your questions if you copy-and-pase the **exact** error message. Often paraphrasing loses much of the detail that we need to help you.

Comment: `&` is indeed logical and, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2

Answer (score -1):

As with all Java boolean operators you need to use the symbol twice

ie `&&` is for and

```
|| is for or
```

Therefore your solution should be

```
(25 <= si && si < 30)
```

Which means that is is is greater than or equal to 25 and less than 30 (si = 25 || 26 || 27 || 28 ||29)

Comment: Nope, `&` is logical and where `&&` is the short circuit version. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2